# How to delete a GCP storage transfer job in python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-transfer

I want to create a small python program (Cloud Functions) to create, run and delete a few GCP storage transfer services.

I can create a GCP storage transfer job as follows,

```py
from google.cloud import storage_transfer

transfer_job_request = storage_transfer.CreateTransferJobRequest({
    'transfer_job': {
        'project_id': project_id,
        'status': storage_transfer.TransferJob.Status.ENABLED,
        'transfer_spec': {
            'gcs_data_source': {
                'bucket_name': 'source-bucket-name',
            },
            'gcs_data_sink': {
                'bucket_name': 'sink-bucket-name',
            }
        }
    }
})
```

However, I can not find any apis to delete a GCP storage tansfer job in either Google api or python library documents.

How to delete a GCP storage tansfer job programmably ?

Thanks.

- [Class StorageTransferServiceClient (1.4.0)  |  Python client library](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storagetransfer/latest/google.cloud.storage_transfer_v1.services.storage_transfer_service.StorageTransferServiceClient)
- [Storage Transfer API  |  Cloud Storage Transfer Service Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest)

Comment: Resolved. I found update_transfer_job (patch API) method, which can change status to DELETED.  https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storagetransfer/latest/google.cloud.storage_transfer_v1.services.storage_transfer_service.StorageTransferServiceClient#google_cloud_storage_transfer_v1_services_storage_transfer_service_StorageTransferServiceClient_update_transfer_job

Comment: You can post your answer so the question will be marked as sovled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.

I found `update_transfer_job` (patch API) method, which can change a job status to `DELETED`.

- [Method: transferJobs.patch  |  Cloud Storage Transfer Service Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/transferJobs/patch)
- [Class StorageTransferServiceClient (1.4.0)  |  Python client library](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storagetransfer/latest/google.cloud.storage_transfer_v1.services.storage_transfer_service.StorageTransferServiceClient#google_cloud_storage_transfer_v1_services_storage_transfer_service_StorageTransferServiceClient_update_transfer_job)